# Python http.server and BaseHTTPRequestHandler - Multi-endpoint API

Tags: python, http.server

By doing `python -m http.server` you can invoke a simple web server which serves files in a directory.

My question is how I can use this to make multiple API endpoints with BaseHTTPRequestHandler

E.g. if I were to make a file called “helloworld.py” in the api directory, with this code:

```py
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler

class app(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header(“Content-type”, “text/plain”)
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(b”Hello World”)
        return
```

And the visited `http://localhost/api/helloworld` it would display the text Hello World.

Is there a way to do this?

TL;DR How can you incorporate BaseHTTPRequestHandler functions into a http.server and execute them as backend handlers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex to check `self.path` for the desired endpoint. It can be applied to `do_POST` as well.

```
import re
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer

class app(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
  def do_GET(self):
    self.send_response(200)
    self.send_header('Content-type','text/html')
    self.end_headers()

    if re.search('/api/helloworld', self.path):
      message = "Hello, World"
      self.wfile.write(bytes(message, "utf8"))

with HTTPServer(('', 8000), app) as server:
  server.serve_forever()
```

`python helloworld.py` will run the server indefinitely, then

```
$ curl localhost:8000/api/helloworld                                                 
Hello, World%
```